# Load a specific tfvars variables file in my Terraform Cloud workspace

Tags: terraform

I wish to specify which `.tfvars` file to load on my workspaces.

Managing variables with files is much easier compared to entering everything in the workspaces. I'll explain.

I have two Worspaces:

- `database-qa`
- `database-prod`

Repo for the workspaces looks like this:

```
├── database/
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── main.qa.tfvars
│   ├── main.prod.tfvars
```

I want to load `main.qa.tfvars` for the `database-qa` workspace, and `main.prod.tfvars` for the `database-prod` workspace, naturally.

I keep the secrets/passwords on the workspace variables for security, and use the `tfvars` for non-sensitive configurations such as names, versions, etc, for convenience. I find it **much** easier than adding all to the variables to the workspace in the cloud.

I checked the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#assigning-values-to-root-module-variables) but I can't find a way to do it.

There is the option to use `*.auto.tfvars` [variable definitions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files) for file names but it will end up loading `qa` and `prod` files and that won't work properly.

Is it possible to do it? What are the alternatives?

Comment: you found any solution?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchPro-Vijay only the answers available here, I used my own.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to create generic Terraform code on root directory, and create one directory per environments.

```
├── database/
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── qa/
│   |   ├── qa.auto.tfvars
│   |   ├── root.tf
│   ├── prod/
│   |   ├── prod.auto.tfvars
│   |   ├── root.tf
```

And in `root.tf`, just point to root directory as local module.

```
module "database" {
  source  = "../"
  cpu = var.cpu
}

[...]
```

On Terraform Cloud, for each workspace, in `General Settings` you have to override `Terraform Working Directory`, and configure directory `qa` or `prod`.

And that's it !

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of reading and help with this [thread](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15966) I found a solution/workaround.

First of all, Terraform Cloud does not support specifying the `.tfvars` file to be loaded in the workspace run, at this time. It is not clear if it is planned on the backlog or not.

Terraform CLI however supports it with the following command and it works fine if you create your pipeline, but risky to run it manually.

```bash
-var-file=<filename>.tfvars
```

Since I'm using Terraform Cloud I ended up with the following configuration. It'll have to be copied to all workspaces, but it works.

```
variable "TFC_WORKSPACE_NAME" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  env = merge(
    yamldecode(file("env/${var.TFC_WORKSPACE_NAME}.yaml"))
  )
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "group" {
  name     = local.env.group
  location = local.env.location
}
```

Comment: Not a perfect solution, because we lose variables metadata (like description), but practical.

Comment: @Antoine indeed, maybe a future update will allow for this.

Comment: Note that you can use `${terraform.workspace}`, so you might not need TFC_WORKSPACE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

one way that I have found to use a tfvars files in terraform cloud workspaces is by adding a workspace env variable (like you would when running terraform locally in your terminal) and then the correct file name like below:

[image: tfvar file in tfcloud]

and here is how it works...

[image: tf files and inputs]

[image: tf output]

you are able to add all of your terraform environment specific variables in the tfvars file , define your required variables in your variables.tf file with all the meta data needed (as @Antonie mentioned) and still be able to pass additional workspace vars for things like secrets etc without putting them in plain text in your repo tfvars files

Answer (score 0):

I think Terraform Cloud's idea is that you set variables for each workspace using their the [Cloud Web Interface](https://app.terraform.io), [or with the API](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/api-docs/variable-sets).

So in the Terraform Cloud Web UI, click on your workspace and there is a menu item "Variables".  Manually type them in one-by-one.

For each deployed instance you create a workspace and set the variables differently as required.  This equates to the `tfvars` file.

One puzzle I encountered was how to configure the workspaces in the `.tf` configuration, as their examples all assumed one workspace and used the `name` parameter.  Instead I was able to *tag* the related workspaces with the UI, then use that tag in the `tf` config something like this...

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.5.0"
  cloud {
    organization = "Acme"
    workspaces {
      tags = ["database"]
    }
  }
}
```

There is some hard-to-find discussion of this topic [buried in the documentation here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cloud-docs/workspaces/variables/managing-variables).

You can also group collections of variables into "Variable Sets" and attach different sets to different workspaces.  In 2023 there was a [tutorial here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/cloud-get-started/cloud-create-variable-set)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you were able to specify a tfvar file to automatically include for a given workspace. I prefer to have variables declared in code like this (unless they're sensitive of course).

This is my current workaround:

1. For each variable with an env/workspace-specific value, define a variable object with a key for each env:

```
# variables.tf

variable "app_service_plan_sku" {
  type = object({
    prod    = string
    staging = string
  })
}

variable "db_backup_retention_days" {
  type = object({
    prod    = number
    staging = number
  })
}
```

2. In your resources, key the variable with the current workspace:

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app" {
  name                = "${var.project}-${terraform.workspace}"

  sku_name = var.app_service_plan_sku[terraform.workspace]
}
```

3. Specify values for each env in `env.auto.tfvars`:

```
app_service_plan_sku = {
  prod    = "P0v3"
  staging = "B1"
}

db_backup_retention_days = {
  prod    = 30
  staging = 7
}
```